# Load multiple images from Firestore in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Assuming that i have firebase collection within i have some records like this :

`Product { name : "Speaker", image_name: "spkr01.png" }`

in addition, the image with name  **(spkr01.png)** already stored in firestore,

i already loaded all products from database, so how to load every image for corresponds products in listview

i have tried some solution, but i didn't make it to work even one image it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to store image URL instead of image name. And, I assume you meant your uploaded to Firebase Storage. Get image url after you upload to Storage and write image URL to product's image_url parameter.

Comment: thanks, this what am looking for. it's work better then image name